# Seomatic - show only global site title

Tags: plugin-seomatic

Right now my homepage title looks like:

```
Home page - SiteName
```

But i want it to look like this:

```
SiteName
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you remove the standard title tag placed in the `_layout.html` file by craft?

This line is probably breaking your SEO title: `<title>{% if title is defined %}{{ title }} - {% endif %}{{ siteName }}</title>` This is found inside the `<head>` tags

If not you should navigate to SEO > Site Meta and take a look in the settings there. The only problem then is that you could only disable the site name being placed not the title. But I guess its the line of code you still have in your _layout

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else in my situation who ends up here:

I had already removed the standard `<title>` tag from my layout.

I was trying to remove "Home - " from my Homepage title using the setting under:

```
SEOmatic > Global SEO > SEO Title Source
```

...but I couldn't understand why this had no effect on the frontend.

Eventually realised there is an individual setting for every section!

```
SEOmatic > Content SEO > [Section Name] > SEO Title Source
```

I just needed to change the Homepage section to use `Custom Text` and leave the box blank